# Ruled surface generated by a rod and its shadow

Tags: differential-geometry

The sun is shines down the z-axis direction. A thin rod $OP$ of unit length has one end $O$ hinged at origin. Other end $P$ moves, making  angle $\gamma$ to the z-axis while its  shadow in $xy$ plane makes an angle $\delta$ to the x-axis.

How to find a ruled surface parameterization described by rod in 3d if $ \mu = \sin \gamma/ \sin \delta $ remains constant?

Started solving with direction cosines.For $P$..

$$ x =\cos \alpha ,\, y= \cos \beta, \, z= \cos \gamma $$

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing something. I understand $\gamma$ as the polar angle for the rod and $\delta$ s the azimuthal one. So, for all the points in the surface, they are related by the relation $\gamma=\arcsin(\mu\sin\delta)$. the rod is along the radial distance $r$. The parametrization would be $r=u;\theta=v;\phi=\arcsin(\mu\sin v)$

Comment: I thought similarly but for my case $ \phi + \gamma =\pi/2 ;\, r=u;\,\theta=v;\,\phi=\arccos(\mu\sin v)? $

Comment: I understood $\gamma$ as the polar angle, but it was the latitude. So, the relation is as you say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of each point in the rod is defined by its distance form the center and by two angles. We can understand one of them, $\gamma$, as the latitude and the other, $\delta$, as the azimuth to relate them to spherical coordinates $(r,\phi,\theta)$

The relation between $\gamma$ and $\delta$ is said to be such that $\mu = \sin \gamma/ \sin \delta$ is constant. Now,

$\gamma=\pi/2-\phi$, with $\phi$ the polar angle and $\delta=\theta$ with $\theta$ the azimuthal angle and the relation is $\mu=\cos\phi/\sin\theta$

So, for all the points in the surface, they are related by $\phi=\arccos(\mu\sin\theta)$ and the rod is along the radial distance r. One parametrization is

$$\begin{cases}
   r=u\\
   \phi=\arccos(\mu\sin v)\\
   \theta=v
\end{cases}$$

I've tried to draw this surface with [GeoGebra](https://ggbm.at/X2jDvTPJ) but this program has not the capability to directly draw in spherical coordinates. The surface in cartesian is:

$$\begin{cases}
   x=u\sqrt{1-\mu^2\sin^2v}\cos v\\
   y=u\sqrt{1-\mu^2\sin^2v}\sin v\\
   z=u\mu\sin v
\end{cases}$$

I've checked it for values $\mu>1$. It has no tangent plane along the $z$ axis.